# make:controller で作成すると use App\Http\Requests が書かれているのは何故？

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

コントローラーをコマンドで作成すると、

```
use App\Http\Requests;
```

が付いてくるのですが、なぜでしょうか？試しに消しても動きます。
何か拡張を想定していたりするのでしょうか？Laravel5 を使える方、教えて頂けると助かります。

Answer (score 1):

Laravel5 では FormRequest を使って入力値のバリデーションを行えるようになりました。この FormRequest を置く名前空間が `App\Http\Requests` です。

コントローラーを生成した時点では FormRequest を使っていないため use を消しても問題ないですし、使う場合でも `App\Http\Requests\HogeRequest` などと完全修飾名で指定すれば use は不要です。クラス単位で use するのも手ですね。

追記：同様の意見が Issue に挙がっていました。

[Remove dead reference from controller stubs by miclf · Pull Request #8656 · laravel/framework](https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/8656)

> It's to make it more convenient to type-hint Form Requests.
>   <sub>--- [Taylor Otwell氏のコメント](https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/8656#issuecomment-100225888)より引用</sub>

参考

- [Laravel5でRequest各種（POST/GET値のやりとり） - Qiita](http://qiita.com/zaburo/items/b80d4ae73efc99b41541#formrequest-laravel5)
- [Laravel 5 はこう変わる！ メソッドインジェクションとFormRequest編 - localdisk](http://localdisk.hatenablog.com/entry/2014/10/01/173347)
- [Validation - Laravel - The PHP Framework For Web Artisans](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation#form-request-validation)

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。 App\Http\Requests\HogeRequest は、
use App\Http\Requests\HogeRequest として
利用する場合は、HogeRequest と指定しますよね。 use App\Http\Requests
というクラス名でない場所をuseしている目的が理解できてませんでした。
この場合、Requests\HogeRequest と指定して利用する目的でしょうか？
わざわざデフォルトで記入される意味が、いまいちすっきりしていないもので・・・

Comment: @Unity開発者 確かに中途半端な気もしたのでリポジトリを漁ってみたところ、同じような意見が却下されているのを見つけたので回答に追記しました。 `Requests\HogeRequest` として使える、ということなんでしょうね・・・。[この行が追加されたコミット](https://github.com/laravel/framework/commit/8fa6f778e87132f3ceaaf8ba1367c93095d667d4)を見ても、深い理由はないのかもしれません。